# How can I position the tooltip to make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to make a tooltip that should appear on the top of every navigation bar link and should also be responsive i.e when screen size is smaller than certain `px` say `350px` my navbar should appear vertically align and tooltip should appear on the left or right side of every link on hover.

My navigation bar works perfectly on my Page. It's also responsive as it should be.

PROBLEM:
But tooltip is not working in smaller screen size as it should be. It shows on the top of `nav div` for all link but I want it to left or right side of the links on hover. Please help

```css
.navbar ul{
    margin: 0;padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar li a, .dropbtn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size:larger;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(90, 81, 81);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
.navbar .dropdown{
    display: inline-block;
}*/


/*tooltip CSS*/
.tooltip-text{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip-text::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;margin-left: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #222 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.navbar li:hover .tooltip-text{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width:540px) {
    .navbar li {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Go to Home</span><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Technology Page</span><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Entertainment Page</span><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Science Page</span><a href="#">Science</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Sports Page</span><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">About Page</span><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Contact Page</span><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, the problem was that every tooltip-text was set to be on the top of the page and not of the parent element. I recomend you to use `display: flex;` to make things responsive.

```css
.navbar ul{
    margin: 0;padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar li a, .dropbtn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size:larger;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(90, 81, 81);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
.navbar .dropdown{
    display: inline-block;
}*/


/*tooltip CSS*/
.tooltip-text{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip-text::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #222 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.navbar li:hover .tooltip-text{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

   /* Edited code */

@media screen and (max-width:540px) {
    .navbar li {
        float: none;
    }
    
    .tooltip-text {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        padding: 1px 3px;
        margin-left: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #333;
        margin-top: 2vh;
        color: white;
        border: 0.5px solid black;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tooltip-text::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
        top: 20%;
        margin: 0 0 0 53%;
        border-width: 6px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #222 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Go to Home</span><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Technology Page</span><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Entertainment Page</span><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Science Page</span><a href="#">Science</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Sports Page</span><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">About Page</span><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><span class="tooltip-text">Contact Page</span><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It working...I appreciate your help.

Comment: And also You said tooltip-text should be set on the parent element so can you explain how and what should I do to achieve it.

Comment: @Kusan2030 Well, when you use the `top` property you are positioning all the elements that have it on the top of the page, it doesn't matter if your parent element (the container) has `bottom: 0;` . So, instead of using `top` you should use `margin`, which positionates the element according to the position of the parent.